# R: Why do some special characters in colum name get replaced automatically?

Tags: r, xts

In some columns of a xts timeseries or data frame I have a special character like ~. This works without problems. However some lines of code replace these ~ with a . and this is a problem. For example merge.xts replaces these characters. How can I avoid that? My current workaround is just to rename the column names again after any operation affecting them but I hope there is an easier solution?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

R sometimes (quite often) uses [non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html). For example `lm()` function uses formula that looks like `y ~ x + z` and R translates this to [model.frame](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/model.frame.html). Because of that if you use some special characters like `~` things could get messy. A made up example would be variable named `+x` that could easily be translated into `add x to something`. Because of that it is better not to use special characters in the names of your variables (better use letters only). Some functions replace special characters with harmless stuff like dots to minimize the risk of errors and that is exactly what you described.

So the solution is **don't use such characters in variable names** for your own sake. If you really have to, then I would recommend to: (1) replace special characters in names *before doing anything* else, (2) do your stuff, (3) change the names to initial ones.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use these special characters. But I think you've propsed a valid workaround here, thanks a lot